# How do you sort and rank multiple values in ascending order within a calculation form using JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small calculation form that has two tables. Each table calculates a number at the end. My goal is to grab each total from each form and rank each total.

For example if total from section A is 4 and section B is 5 then Section A rank would be 2 and section B rank would be 1.

I've tried adding some logic into JavaScript and I still couldn't figure it out.
I would like to follow the same format that my JavaScript is already in. I am new to JavaScript.

If the run code snippet is displaying correctly please copy and paste the code in a test editor.

I've tried adding logic and putting them in an array and I still could not figure it out.

```js
function calcA1R() {
  var Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1');
  var Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1');
  var Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1');

  var Aa1Val = Aa1.options[Aa1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ab1Val = Ab1.options[Ab1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Ac1Val = Ac1.options[Ac1.selectedIndex].value;

  // returning the sum of the values
  return [parseInt(Aa1Val), parseInt(Ab1Val), parseInt(Ac1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
}

function calcA1() {
  // anything changes displaySum() runs
  displaySumA()

  document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = calcA1R();
}

function displaySumA() {

  document.getElementById('totalA').textContent = calcSumA()
  document.getElementById('totalA2').textContent = calcSumA()

}

function calcSumA() {
  return calcA1R()
}

function calcB1R() {
  var Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ba1');
  var Bb1 = document.getElementById('Bb1');
  var Bc1 = document.getElementById('Bc1');
  var Bd1 = document.getElementById('Bd1');
  var Be1 = document.getElementById('Be1');

  var Ba1Val = Ba1.options[Ba1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bb1Val = Bb1.options[Bb1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bc1Val = Bc1.options[Bc1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Bd1Val = Bd1.options[Bd1.selectedIndex].value;
  var Be1Val = Be1.options[Be1.selectedIndex].value;

  return [parseInt(Ba1Val), parseInt(Bb1Val), parseInt(Bc1Val), parseInt(Bd1Val), parseInt(Be1Val)].reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)

}

function calcB1() {
  // anything changes displaySum() runs
  displaySumB()
  //Adds to points awarded

}

function displaySumB() {
  document.getElementById('totalB').textContent = calcSumB()
  document.getElementById('totalB2').textContent = calcSumB()
}

function calcSumB() {
  return calcB1R()
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>Section A</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Aa1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 2</td>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ab1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Question 3</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcA1();" id="Ac1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
    <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
    <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br><br>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueHead">
    <td><b>Section B</b></td>
    <td><b>Value</b></td>
    <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 4</td>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Ba1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 5</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bb1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 6 </td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bc1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 7</td>
    <td align="center">3</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Bd1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 8</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">
      <select class="select" onChange="calcB1();" id="Be1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <tr>
      <tr class="blueHead">
        <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
        <td align="center"><b>13</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalB"></span></b></td>
      </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Totals Points Earned</td>
    <td>Ranked</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>
      <div><span id="totalA2"></span></td>
    <td>rank goes here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>
      <div><span id="totalB2"></span></td>
    <td>rank goes here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: u should put the `javascript` code inside `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: If my answer helped u with your question, pls mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

U can just make a function `updateRanks` and call it each time an `input` is `changed`, i.e after each call of `calcA1()` and `calcB1()`.
I've rewritten your javascript code to give u a better example. Hope it helps.

```
let Aa1 = document.getElementById('Aa1')
let Ab1 = document.getElementById('Ab1')
let Ac1 = document.getElementById('Ac1')
let Ba1 = document.getElementById('Ba1')
let Bb1 = document.getElementById('Bb1')
let Bc1 = document.getElementById('Bc1')
let Bd1 = document.getElementById('Bd1')
let Be1 = document.getElementById('Be1')

function calcA1() {
  document.getElementById('totalA2').innerHTML = parseInt(Aa1.value) + parseInt(Ab1.value) + parseInt(Ac1.value)
  updateRanks()
}

function calcB1() {
  document.getElementById('totalB2').innerHTML = parseInt(Ba1.value) + parseInt(Bb1.value) + parseInt(Bc1.value) + parseInt(Bd1.value) + parseInt(Be1.value)
  updateRanks()
}

function updateRanks() {
  let totalA = parseInt(document.getElementById('totalA2').innerHTML)
  let totalB = parseInt(document.getElementById('totalB2').innerHTML)
  let rankA = document.getElementById('rank-a')
  let rankB = document.getElementById('rank-b')
  if (totalA > totalB) {
    rankA.innerHTML = 1
    rankB.innerHTML = 2
  } else if (totalA < totalB) {
    rankA.innerHTML = 2
    rankB.innerHTML = 1
  } else {
    rankA.innerHTML = 1
    rankB.innerHTML = 1
  }
}
```

```html
    ...
        <td id="rank-a">rank goes here</td>
    ...
        <td id="rank-b">rank goes here</td>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I made another sample code.

This makes you able to add or remove questions and even sections without editing any javascript code and result table.

```js
(function() {

update();

document.querySelectorAll('#questions select').forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.addEventListener('change', function() {
        update();
    });

});

function update() {

    var results = [];

    document.querySelectorAll('#questions table').forEach(function(elm, sectionIndex) {
        var section = elm.getAttribute('section');
        results[sectionIndex] = {
            section: section,
            total: 0
        }
        elm.querySelectorAll('select').forEach(function(elm, rowIndex) {
            results[sectionIndex]['total'] += parseInt(elm.value);
        });
    });


    //sort by total value and set rank
    results.sort(compareByTotal);
    var prevRank = 1;
    var prevTotal = 0;
    results.forEach(function(result, index) {
        if (result.total == prevTotal) {
            results[index].rank = prevRank;
        } else {
            results[index].rank = index + 1;
        }
        prevTotal = result.total;
        prevRank = result.rank;
    });

    //sort back to default
    results.sort(compareBySection);

    //Display result
    var html = '';
    results.forEach(function(result, index) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + result['section'] + "</td><td>" + result['total'] + "</td><td>" + result['rank'] + "</td></tr>";
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
    });
}

function compareByTotal(a, b) {
    if (a.total < b.total) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a.total > b.total) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function compareBySection(a, b) {
    if (a.section < b.section) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.section > b.section) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


})();
```

```html
<div id="questions">
    <table section="A">
        <tr class="blueHead">
            <td><b>Section A</b></td>
            <td><b>Value</b></td>
            <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 1</td>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 2</td>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Question 3</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueHead">
            <td class="subtotal">Section A. Total</td>
            <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>

    <table section="B">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueHead">
            <td><b>Section B</b></td>
            <td><b>Value</b></td>
            <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 4</td>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 5</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 6 </td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 7</td>
            <td align="center">3</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 8</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <tr class="blueHead">
                <td class="subtotal">Section B. Total</td>
                <td align="center"><b>13</b></td>
                <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalB"></span></b></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table section="C">
        <tr class="blueHead">
            <td><b>Section C</b></td>
            <td><b>Value</b></td>
            <td><b>Awarded</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 9</td>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Question 10</td>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Question 11</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
            <td align="center">
                <select>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueHead">
            <td class="subtotal">Section C. Total</td>
            <td align="center"><b>4</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b><div><span id="totalA"></span></div></b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Totals Points Earned</td>
            <td>Ranked</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="result">

    </tbody>

</table>
```